# A silly question: How can I recognize a jar file among a bunch of files?

Tags: java, maven, jar, web-crawler

I have a project that has been written in java. It used Maven as manager of library. In particular, 'Assembly' plugin has been used for creating the jar that I need to execute for running the whole program.

[Here there is the bunch of files.](https://github.com/fabiana001/anacAnalysis/tree/master/crawler) How can I recognize a jar file among them? How can I exactly execute the whole program starting from the jar? I know that I can use command in the prompt for running it. But for doing that I need your help: which is the jar file among them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Answer (score 2):

There is no jar file among them, the project is a source code, not built yet...
if you want to run it you should either open it in your editor (run/build), or use the command prompt.
hope this was useful.

Comment: The following error is displayed running the assembly:plugin. 

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc (xjc) on project crawler: Execution xjc of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter`

Comment: @GiovanniNicolazzo add <pluginManagement> </pluginManagement> before <plugins> tag, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257811/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-codemodel-codewriter-with-jdk9) will help you and looks like you have missing class in the git [repo](https://github.com/fabiana001/anacAnalysis/tree/master/crawler) you have been using.