# Getting error while generating jaxb classes in java11

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11, jaxb2-maven-plugin

Build is the maven plugin code i used in pom.xml.This I have modified for 2.2 version.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>/src/main/resources/adapters/charging/payments/wsdls/charging-payments-v1.wsdl</source>
                </sources>
                <packageName>com.equifax.icc.charging.payment.service.wsdl</packageName>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc (xjc) on project payment-manager-domain: Execution xjc of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/2.2/jaxb2-maven-plugin-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.2.11/jaxb-jxc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M3/qdox-2.0-M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.5/plexus-compiler-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/vxa90/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter
```

Do we need to add the dependencies for the Codewriter or I am trying something wrong.Also if the codewriter class is needed, which dependency needs to be added?

Comment: Probably this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257811/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-codemodel-codewriter-with-jdk9)

Comment: I have already tried this option.But no luck.Seems like isnot able to find the Codewriter. I Have tried adding the dependency for this class, yet the issue remains same.

Comment: Do you use `JDK` or `JRE`?

Comment: I am using JDK 11.0.1